# Name conventions for xibs

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, naming-conventions, xib

I've been looking at the sample code and sometimes Apple names xib files `ClassNameView` and sometimes `ClassNameViewController`. The `ClassName` is always a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, which had me wonder what convention to use when naming a xib. I would think View as it's not really the `ViewController`, but curious on what *the* convention is or at least what your naming conventions are for xibs.

Comment: This confuses me as well. I hope others can continue to chime in here as I can see valid arguments for *both* styles. it's a IB doc so is clearly a **view** right? But then again the owner is typically a **view controller** and the nib can contain *multiple* views... 

I'm currently in the middle of the road camp looking for a convincing argument to pull me one way or the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ClassNameView since the xib represents the view, not the view controller. I don't think there is a generally accepted convention.

Comment: I did not seem to find a generally accepted convention either. However, I read this blog post at http://www.cimgf.com/2009/05/11/magical-iphone-view-controllers/ that says when using init (not initWithNibName), it assumes the nib is named ClassNameView.

I'll probably go with View because like you said henning, it's not the view controller.

Answer (score 3):

CocoaTouch supports both conventions, with a preference for the shorter form ClassNameView, as per the nib loading process described below when a nib name is not specified (from [the UIViewController documentation, under nibName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName)):

> Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the
>   following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as
>      in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks
>      for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller
>      class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks
>      for a MyViewController.nib file.

So as other have said, it's a matter of preference! I personally like the shorter version but can see the logic in both.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use ClassNameViewController since I set the File's Owner to that class and it seems strange to name the file after something that's a sub-object of the object the nib represents. Like you, I have seen it both ways in sample code and I did see a blog post about Cocoa explicitly looking for ClassNameView in some cases, but I haven't had any problems using ClassNameViewController.