# iOS - Abbreviating XXXViewController to XXXVC bad or ok?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode4, naming-conventions

Since every view controller ends with "ViewController" would it be evil to simply abbreviate it as "VC"? I know the Apple Docs say not to abbreviate things and make the names meaningful but isn't this something that's just obvious what it is? I find it lengthy and verbose to type ViewController after every single one. Also, xcode 4 automatically names the nib file the same as the header and class files. Do you remove the "Controller" part of it?

What are your naming conventions and why did you choose to do it that way?

Thanks

Comment: I was just wrestling with this same question recently. I'm going to try the VC abbreviation. I find it hard to find the correct file in the navigation sidebar with `ViewController` all over the place. One caveat: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11450070/130910. The compiler drops `Controller` to look for nibs. Not such a biggy. I'm moving away from nibs and storyboards too - bad for refactoring, git, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Xcode, you shouldn't have to type the full name every time.  Auto-complete handles that for you.

In general, avoiding abbreviation makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.  Sure you know what VC means, but someone else 3 years from now might not understand what you were doing.

In this specific case, it may not make tons of sense, but naming conventions are conventions.  We follow them in most cases to make our lives (and others) easier in the future.

Always imagine that the person who will eventually maintain your code is a big mean guy with a hair-trigger temper who knows where you live.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand the reasons for naming conventions and promote them when they make sense but this one just always seemed to bug me. I just wanted to see if anyone else shared my thoughts on this or did something else and for what reason.

Comment: I've been in software engineering for going on 16 years and naming conventions have always been important.  I've never had a job where we ignored rules like that.  For whatever that's worth.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite what people seem to say Apple has excellent documentation. They have even gone so far as to provide a [Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1) document.

This not only provides some good examples for you to use, but also helps to understand the way name, conventions and abbreviations are used in the Frameworks.

Comment: I've read the coding guidelines and don't have a problem with Apple's documentation. I frequently use it and find it very helpful. This question was more of a "What do you like to do?" type of question.